# O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (400) Solicitação Incorreta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-web-api, restful

Criei dois métodos, um para autenticação via certificado do tipo A1 e A3 e outro para enviar um xml, ambos fazem a requisição em uma api rest do cliente.

No método de autenticação, envio os dados do meu certificado para o cliente e tenho o retorno de um "Set-Token" com informações do usuário, "X-CSRF-Token" Token de prevenção contra ataques CSRF e "X-CSRF-Expiration" com a data de expiração.

Método de autenticação.

```
public void CarregaCertificado()
        {

            string destinationUrl = "https://val.portalunico.siscomex.gov.br/portal/api/autenticar";
            string requestXml = "Aqui é a string do xml";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);

            X509Certificate2 oCertificado;
            var oX509Cert = new X509Certificate2();
            var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            var collection = store.Certificates;

            var collection2 = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false);
            var scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(collection2,
              "Certificado(s) Digital(is) disponível(is)", "Selecione o certificado digital para uso no aplicativo",
               X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);


            if (scollection.Count == 0)
            {
                var msgResultado =
                    "Nenhum certificado digital foi selecionado ou o certificado selecionado está com problemas.";
                MessageBox.Show(msgResultado, "Advertência", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                oX509Cert = scollection[0];
                oCertificado = oX509Cert;
                request.ClientCertificates.Add(oCertificado);


                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add("Role-Type", "DEPOSIT");

                request.Method = "POST";

                HttpWebResponse response;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                string tokenResponse = string.Empty;
                string csrfTokenResponse = string.Empty;
                string csrfExpirionResponse = string.Empty;
                string keepAlive = string.Empty;
                string connection = string.Empty;
                string contentLength = string.Empty;
                string contentType = string.Empty;
                string date = string.Empty;
                string server = string.Empty;


                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    tokenResponse = response.Headers["Set-Token"];
                    csrfTokenResponse = response.Headers["X-CSRF-Token"];
                    csrfExpirionResponse = response.Headers["X-CSRF-Expiration"];
                    keepAlive = response.Headers["Keep-Alive"];
                    connection = response.Headers["Connection"];
                    contentLength = response.Headers["Content-Length"];
                    contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
                    date = response.Headers["Date"];
                    server = response.Headers["Server"];



                    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();

                }

               EnvioXML(requestXml, tokenResponse, csrfTokenResponse, csrfExpirionResponse);

            }
        }

Recebo os dados após autenticação sem problemas!
Depois tento enviar o xml.
Método de envio do xml.

 public void EnvioXML(string requestXml, string tokenResponse, string csrfTokenResponse, string csrfExpirionResponse)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://val.portalunico.siscomex.gov.br/cct/api/ext/carga/entrega-conteiner");
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestXml);

            request.ContentType = "application/xml";

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", tokenResponse);

            request.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", csrfTokenResponse);           

            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            request.ContentLength = 1;
            request.SendChunked = true;
            request.Method = "POST";           

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Stream responseStream1 = response.GetResponseStream();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Por favor galera, alguém me ajude!

Comment: Você já utilizou o fiddler para ver exatemente o que está enviando ao servidor?

Comment: Não conheço o fiddler, mais utilizei o postman mais tenho o mesmo retorno.

Comment: Nesse caso de fato você está montando o post de forma incorreta.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo de código para envio em visual basic.

```
' Variaveis
Dim cSiteDUE                As String
Dim objHTTP                 As New XMLHTTP
Dim cToken                  As String
Dim cCSRF                   As String
Dim objDom                  As New DOMDocument
Dim lTesteXML               As Integer
Dim cXML                    As String

' Autenticacao
On Error Resume Next
cSiteDUE = "https://val.portalunico.siscomex.gov.br/portal/api/autenticar"
objHTTP.open "POST", cSiteDUE, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Role-Type", "IMPEXP"
objHTTP.send
If (Err) Then
    MsgBox Error, vbInformation, "Mensagem"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Leitura das Informacoes
' cRetorno = objHTTP.responseText
If (Err) Then
    MsgBox Error, vbInformation, "Mensagem"
    Exit Sub
End If
cToken = objHTTP.getResponseHeader("Set-Token")
cCSRF = objHTTP.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token")

' Leitura do XML
lTesteXML = objDom.loadXML("c:\due\teste1.xml")

On Error Resume Next
Close #1
Open "c:\due\teste1.xml" For Input As #1
If (Err) Then
    MsgBox Error, vbInformation, "Mensagem"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0

' Looping de Leitura
cXML = ""
Do While Not EOF(1)

    ' Leitura da Linha
    Line Input #1, cLinha

    ' Processo
    cXML = cXML & Trim(cLinha)


Loop


' Envio da DU-e
cSiteDUE = "https://val.portalunico.siscomex.gov.br/due/api/ext/due"
objHTTP.open "POST", cSiteDUE, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", cToken
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-CSRF-Token", cCSRF
objHTTP.send cXML
If (Err) Then
    MsgBox Error, vbInformation, "Mensagem"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Leitura das Informacoes
cRetorno = objHTTP.responseText
If (Err) Then
    MsgBox Error, vbInformation, "Mensagem"
    Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox cRetorno
```

Comment: Este procedimento está enviando e recebendo a informação corretamente.

Comment: Consegui enviar o Xml, o problema estava no Xml.